# Changing the standard "message" on PIC24F shown on Android

Tags: pic, eeprom

I am working on an android accessory development.
Currently whenever I plugin my Android device to the PIC24F (which I had programmed in the PIC24F) but I haven't installed in the Android phone

It display:
"Accessory Development Starter Kit (PIC24F) for Android(tm)

No installation applications work with this USB accessory. Learn more about this accessory at the microchip"

I tried using MPLAB to read/access and find the sentence but there isn't any result.

**How can I modify the sentence?**

The software I am using:

[MPLAB IDE](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en536656) Version 8.73 MPLAB C Compiler for PIC24 and dsPIC v3.30

The device/tools I am using:

[DM240415 - PIC24F Accessory Development Starter Kit for Android](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en553673)

Comment: Are you using your own code or some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way to change the default message!

Let say the default displays this:
"Accessory Development Starter Kit (PIC24F) for Android(tm)

No installation applications work with this USB accessory. Learn more about this accessory at the microchip"

It seem that when programming to the PIC24F in MPLAB, we have to declare the manufacturer, version, uri, description, etc. The Android device will then automatically get the value when the accessory are attached. Unfortunately, we can't change the body part of the message.

**Sample Example of the Output**

E.g. My description is "Hello World" and my uri is "www.helloworld.com".

It will display:

"Hello World

No installation applications work with this USB accessory. Learn more about this accessory at the www.helloworld.com"

Answer (score 2):

16-bit PIC24 and dsPIC devices don't have any EEPROM! They only have flash memory, but EEPROM can be emulated:

http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en530593

Comment: So it isn't the EEPROM that store the message. If I want to edit the message, is it possible?

Comment: You are right, PIC24F doesn't have a EEPROM! :)